# Git merge-edit between branches, compared to Perforce

Tags: git, perforce, cherry-pick

When I used **Perforce**, I did a compare between branches to see what CL was not merged. I used:

```
p4 interchanges //depot/branches/$from_branch/... //depot/branches/$to_branch/...
```

It recognized it perfectly, even if there was a **merge-edit** (a merge and an edit before submit).

Now I use **Git**, and I use:

```
git log origin/"$from_branch" ^origin/"$to_branch" --no-merges
```

We usually do a cherry pick (instead of a merge) between branches. We also do an edit before we commit and push (so it's kind of a **merge-edit**)
The command does not work, because the commits are different...

Any idea how I can still find what commits are missing between branches?

Comment: I don't completely follow what you are doing (as I never did extensive work with Perforce), but I will comment that when you cherry-pick a commit in Git from one branch to another, you actually create a _new_ commit.  So, Git can't easily track them at this point.

Comment: There are git workflows which allow you to track merges cleanly with git, giving you similar power to what you get with Perforce. Here's a brilliant description of how it works: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180323-01/?p=98325

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use notes and cherry-pick -x to track commits that were "merged"